# window is not defined - react-draft-wysiwyg used with next js (ssr)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am working on a rich text editor used for converting plain html to editor content with next js for ssr. I got this error window is not defined so I search a solution to this github [link](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/893)

It used a dynamic import feature of next js.

Instead of importing the Editor directly `import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";`

It uses this code to dynamically import the editor

```
const Editor = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then(mod => mod.Editor);
  },
  { ssr: false }
);
```

But still I'm getting this error though I already installed this react-draft-wysiwyg module

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
| var Editor = dynamic(function () {
>   return import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then(function (mod) {
|     return mod.Editor;
|   });
```

And this is my whole code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
// import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Editor = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then(mod => mod.Editor);
  },
  { ssr: false }
);

class MyEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
  }

  onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          wrapperClassName="rich-editor demo-wrapper"
          editorClassName="demo-editor"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          placeholder="The message goes here..."
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

Please help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: I have samo bug with log : `\react-draft-wysiwyg.js:1:393)` undefined window  ... Is it same error point ?

Comment: what is the error message? it think its because were rendering the component on server side where window is not defined

Comment: actually, my code is the same as yours, and it works fine at my project

Answer (score 18):

Here is a workaround

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { EditorProps } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg'

// install @types/draft-js @types/react-draft-wysiwyg and @types/draft-js @types/react-draft-wysiwyg for types

const Editor = dynamic<EditorProps>(
  () => import('react-draft-wysiwyg').then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Comment: The dynamic import fixes the window not being defined error while installing types and using EditorProps fixed the type error in Typescript

Comment: With this solution I have a type error: Argument of type '() => Promise<ComponentClass<EditorProps, any> | FunctionComponent<EditorProps> | ComponentModule<EditorProps> | typeof Editor>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<EditorProps> | Loader<EditorProps>'.

Answer (score 8):

The dynamic one worked for me

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import('react-draft-wysiwyg').then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
)
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const TextEditor = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-5">
        <Editor
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default TextEditor
```

Answer (score 2):

**Draft.js WYSWYG** with **Next.js** and Strapi Backend, Create and View Article with **Image Upload**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html'; 
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Editor = dynamic(
() => import('react-draft-wysiwyg').then(mod => mod.Editor),
{ ssr: false })  

import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";


export default class ArticleEditor extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
}

onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
        editorState,
    });
    this.props.handleContent(
        convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()
    ));
};

  uploadImageCallBack = async (file) => {
    const imgData = await apiClient.uploadInlineImageForArticle(file);
    return Promise.resolve({ data: { 
      link: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}${imgData[0].formats.small.url}`
    }});
  }

render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
        <>
            <Editor
                editorState={editorState}
                toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                editorClassName="editor-class"
                onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
                toolbar={{
                    options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker', 'link', 'embedded', 'emoji', 'image', 'history'],
                    inline: { inDropdown: true },
                    list: { inDropdown: true },
                    textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
                    link: { inDropdown: true },
                    history: { inDropdown: true },
                    image: {
                        urlEnabled: true,
                        uploadEnabled: true,
                        uploadCallback: this.uploadImageCallBack,
                        previewImage: true,
                        alt: { present: false, mandatory: false }
                    },
                }}
            />
            <textarea
                disabled
                value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Any Dropdown not working with next.js.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
import { EditorProps } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Editor = dynamic<EditorProps>(
  async () => {
    const mod = await import('react-draft-wysiwyg');
    return { default: mod.Editor as unknown as ComponentType<EditorProps> };
  },
  { ssr: false }
);
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451068/window-is-not-defined-react-draft-wysiwyg-used-with-next-js-ssr#
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import() Statement:

Ensure that your dynamic import statement is correctly importing the component and that the file path is accurate. Also, make sure that the component you are trying to import is a default export.

```
// Correct import statement
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'));

// Incorrect import statement (e.g., missing default export)
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./MyComponent').then(module => module.MyComponent));
```

This works for me

```
 import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// This line dynamically imports the Froala Editor component, 
// and sets it to not load on the server (ssr: false)
const FroalaEditor = dynamic(
  () => import('react-froala-wysiwyg'),
  { ssr: false }
);

function MyComponent() {
  const config = {
    // Add your Froala configuration here
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FroalaEditor config={config} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to return the `Editor` after React updates the DOM using `useEffect` hook. For instance:

```js
const [editor, setEditor] = useState<boolean>(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setEditor(true)
  })

  return (
    <>
      {editor ? (
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          wrapperClassName="rich-editor demo-wrapper"
          editorClassName="demo-editor"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          placeholder="The message goes here..."
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  )
```

Comment: the problem does not happen when the component is loaded, but when the component is imported.