# React "window is not defined" when using react-globe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Code I try to copy:
https://codesandbox.io/s/knhlr?file=/src/index.tsx:0-691

Dependencies:
"@next/font": "^13.0.5",
"eslint-config-next": "13.0.4",
"next": "13.0.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"sharp": "^0.31.2",
"three": "0.109.0",
"react-globe": "5.0.2",
"es6-tween": "5.5.10"

My Next.js (React) code renders a white page and writes in the console: "window is not defined"

```
"use client";

import ReactGlobe from "react-globe";

import markers from "./markers";
import markerRenderer from "./markerRenderer";

const options = {
    markerRenderer,
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ReactGlobe
                height="100vh"
                globeTexture="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisrzhou/react-globe/main/textures/globe_dark.jpg"
                markers={markers}
                width="100vw"
                options={options}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The duplicate issue is not the right one, you are in a situation where importing the module crashes the server, while the question marked as duplicate is the situation where importing work but not rendering.
The correct solution here is using next/dynamic as listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679783/window-not-defined-or-document-not-defined-when-importing-module-in-next-js

Answer (score 1):

I thought client components are only rendered on the browser but apparently client components **can also be pre-rendered on the server** and hydrated on the client.

See this discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42319

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```js
"use client";

import ReactGlobe from "react-globe";

import markers from "./markers";
import markerRenderer from "./markerRenderer";

const options = {
    markerRenderer,
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
              typeof window !== undefined ?
                <ReactGlobe
                  height="100vh"
                  globeTexture="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisrzhou/react-globe/main/textures/globe_dark.jpg"
                  markers={markers}
                  width="100vw"
                  options={options}
                />
              :
                null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Update:**

You can fix it by dynamically import your library:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
```

```js
const ReactGlobe = dynamic(import('react-globe'), { ssr: false });
```

Comment: Yes. Same error. "window is not defined"

Comment: @Stautenberg I updated my answer. Could you test the new solution ?