# ReferenceError: window is not defined in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, reference, window

```
error - ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ZZZ\my_app\node_modules\react-flip-page\dist\index.js:1:254)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at react-flip-page (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:76:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/Page2.js:9:73)
    at ./src/pages/Page2.js (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:32:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/index.js:11:73)
    at ./src/pages/index.js (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:43:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:97:39)
    at D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:98:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ZZZ\my_app\.next\server\pages\index.js:101:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.requirePage (D:\ZZZ\my_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:88:12)
    at D:\ZZZ\my_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:49:73
    at async Object.loadComponentsImpl [as loadComponents] (D:\ZZZ\my_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:49:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (D:\ZZZ\my_app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:599:36) {
  page: '/'
}
```

I am using react-flip-page-library and it is throwing this error even though I am not using node.

I am using react-flip-page-library and it is throwing this error even though I am not using node.

Comment: Did you attempt server-side rendering?

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what's going on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)

Comment: You seem to be in the situation where importing the package crashes the server, which is the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679783/window-not-defined-or-document-not-defined-when-importing-module-in-next-js).
The question listed by @YoussoufOumar is slightly related but a different scenario. I've crafted a complete answer covering all use situations there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556387/5513532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
const FlipBook = dynamic(() => import('react-flip-page'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```